# Integrating reCaptcha into existing contact.php

Tags: php, recaptcha

I'm having trouble integrating the new Google reCaptcha into my existing form handling php script. Previously, it worked absolutely fine with the contact.html page redirecting the form to the contact.php email handler, but I kept getting a load of spam, hence the desire to use reCaptcha.

I use a separate php file to handle the emailing. The relevant contact.html code is as follows:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">

<div class="messages"></div>
<div class="controls">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_name">Name *</label>
                <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your name *" required="required" data-error="Name is required">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email address *" required="required" data-error="A valid email is required">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_phone">Telephone</label>
                <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter a contact telephone number (optional)">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
         <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
                <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your message *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please enter your message"></textarea>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        <p>
          <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfsexAUAAAAAF_qKlK7De8kA7XM2MGrGKTyK60M"></div></p>

         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Submit"></p>
         <br><p class="text-muted"><strong>*</strong> These fields are required.</p>
         </form>
```

The existing code from the contact.php file is this:

```
<?php


$from= "example@example.com";
$sendTo = "me@me.com";
$subject = "New message from contact form";
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message');
$okMessage = 'Thank you for your message. One of the team will be in touch as soon as possible.';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';


try
{
$emailText = "You have new message from contact form\n=============================\n";

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

    if (isset($fields[$key])) {
        $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
    }
}

mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);

$responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
$responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
$encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo $encoded;
}
else {
echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

This currently works fine, but when I try and integrate the reCaptcha validation into the php, the email doesn't generate and the success message in the php doesn't display on the webpage.

Any help in integrating the reCaptcha validation into the php file would be greatly appreciated!!

EDIT: the  tag for the reCaptcha is in the  of the html as required, and the widget displays and functions fine on the site. However, every example piece of code that I've tried to integrate into the existing php has not worked and the emails don't generate (hence why I've left it out in the php file above). Thanks in advance!

EDIT 2: I have revised the php script and attempted the clean it up following CoolCodeGuy's helpful comments. However, given my budget php skills, it now doesn't work. Please help!!

```
            <?php


    $from= "example@example.com";
    $sendTo = "me@me.com";
    $subject = "New message from contact form";
    $fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message');
    $okMessage = 'Thank you for your message. One of the team will be in touch as soon as possible.';
    $errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $privatekey = "xxxxxxxxx"; //whatever your PRIVATE key is
    $response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $data = json_decode($response);

    try
    {
    $emailText = "You have new message from contact form\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    //verifcation passed
    if (isset($fields[$key])) {
        $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
    }
}

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);
    $responseArray = $okMessage;
   }
   else
   {
   //verification failed
   $responseArray = $errorMessage;
   }

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
    }
    else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the whole of your code to the way I would have done it (I run a social-networking site).

```
        <?php

    $sendTo = "me@me.com";
    $subject = "New message from contact form";
    $headers .= 'From: <example@example.com>' . "\r\n";

    $name = @$_POST['name'];
    $phone = @$_POST['phone'];
    $email = @$_POST['email'];
    $message = @$_POST['message'];

    $okMessage = 'Thank you for your message. One of the team will be in touch as soon as possible.';
    $errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $privatekey = "xxxxxxxxx"; //whatever your PRIVATE key is
    $response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $data = json_decode($response);

    $emailText = "Name: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Email: $email \n Message: $message";

if (isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true) {

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, $headers);
    $responseArray = $okMessage;
   }
   else
   {
   //verification failed
   $responseArray = $errorMessage;
   }

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
    }
    else {
    echo $responseArray;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. The emails now generate fine (assuming you pass the reCaptcha). However, the success / error messages are still not being generated, either on the page or on a new page. I've tried incorporating the old success code ($responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage); as well as adding the echo $responseArray['message']; at the bottom of the php script but still no luck...

Comment: @JoeFlaherty What do you intend for 'if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;' of the code to do? What is $encoded?

Comment: @JoeFlaherty If it's not really that important then I would suggest taking it out because I think it's stopping the else statement and stopping the echo code

Comment: I've found the problem. It was also incorporating two Javascript files: contact.js and validator.js which are part of the Bootstrap suite. I've deleted them from the contact.html file and it now works fine, both with email generation and . Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Incorporate the code below on the contact.php page

```
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $privatekey = ""; //whatever your PRIVATE key is

    $response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    $data = json_decode($response);

    if (isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true) {
   //verification succeeded
    $responseArray = $okMessage;
   }
   else
   {
   //verification failed
   $responseArray = $errorMessage;
   }

echo $responseArray;
```

Comment: You sir, are a star, thank you. Emails now generate fine but I can't get the success / fail messages to work. I've amended up the php in an edit to the original comment (php is not my strong suit as you can probably tell). Please help!!

Comment: @JoeFlaherty See my updated code to incorporate into yours without using arrays (personally I think there too complicated!)

Comment: Thanks. I've tried incorporating it, and it's still not working - no error/success messages or emails. As well as generating the okMessage, I also want it to actually run the email script as well. I've pasted the full revised script into the original comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use javascript Validation, on form tag

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" id="rcaptcha"  data-sitekey="xxxx"></div>
     `      <form action="" method="post" onSubmit="return get_action()"> ` <span id="captcha"  style="color:red" /></span></div>
```

```
   <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
  <script>

  function get_action(form) 
    {
    var v = grecaptcha.getResponse();
if(v.length == 0)
{
    document.getElementById('captcha').innerHTML="You can't leave Captcha Code empty";
    return false;
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('captcha').innerHTML="Captcha completed";
    return true; 
   }
   }
```

Comment: Hard as it may be to believe, I understand even less about JS than I do php. I'm trying to keep things as simple as possible!!